# How do I re-assign the else if in javascript to function the same but typed as elif?

Tags: javascript, optimization, customization

I'm currently doing some JavaScript programming and don't like having to type **else if** everytime I need to use it. I would much rather just type **elif**. I have done tons of research and don't know how I could get something like this... *look at code* ... to work where I can still say elif, but it is recognized as else if and I would be able to use it without the program.

```
elif = else if;
let x = 20;
if (x >= 21) {
  console.log('psych bwah!');
} elif (x <= 19 ) {
  console.log('umm... nope try again bud!');
} else {
  console.log('ladies and gentlemen we gotem!');
}
```

I really want this to work so badly. And it would be so mind pleasing to understand how to rewrite pre-made code in terms that I want to use. Another example of what I'm trying to accomplish would be re-assigning the `console.log()` printing function to something shorter but still does the exact same thing, maybe `c.l()` as a shorter version, just for example though.

Having the ability to assign already usable normal JavaScript code to my own version of code is the task I guess I am trying to accomplish, if that makes sense. This way I can shorthand it and make everything way faster than I'd be able to before. So what I am really looking for is a better/working way, because my current method seen above in the code doesn't work, is maybe some form of a method or other way of changing the name of an if...else keeping the same function just typed/said different in code.

Comment: There is no way to re-assign reserved words. You're unfortunately going to have to learn to use `else if` which honestly is completely fine it just takes some practice to type different things.

Comment: eh, that should be "possible" with a compiler, but... that might be a bit overkill for something that's just an inconvenience.

Comment: You can write your own transpiler for that custom JavaScript dialect, e.g. using [sweet.js](https://www.sweetjs.org/). No, JS has no native capabilities to redefine its syntax.

Comment: But why do you want to do this? This is a really bad idea if you will have other people reading your code.

Comment: I want to do it for personal use and quicker program making. I'm not making my current JS program for other people and yeah, that would be confusing to others who haven't done it themselves. But the goal isn't to make it for others to have a easier time understanding it, rather it is to make it easier for my understanding of it.

Comment: Honestly the effort of typing three extra characters every once in a while will 100% not be the hardest part of using JavaScript.

Comment: Yeah, I understand it is easy to type _else if_, but I was hoping to be able to do this with other things as well, _else if_ was just my 'at the moment' example because that's one I really wanted to change.

Comment: Doesn't your ide have sytnax completion? Down the road you will find yourself scratching your head as to why something doesn't work and that would likely be a culprit somehow.

Comment: lol you don't need a library or a custom compiler. It takes like three lines of code. Everyone in this comment section is just really overthinking it - see my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer:

**Yes, it's possible.**

As a note, it's not a *great idea* to do this for any production projects for a multitude of different reasons, however, it's a rather simple process for toy code or snippets.

### How:

You can create a `text/template` script tag, parse it for **Regular Expressions** or **Plain Text** - just like any other String - replace it with whatever you would like, then place it in a `Function` constructor and call it.

A longer explanation I wrote in an article a while back can be found here: https://medium.com/wdstack/understanding-javascript-micro-templating-f37a37b3b40e

A larger example with a couple of different code adjustments ( for instance instead of `if(a === b || a === c)` you can write `if(a === b || c)` ) can be found here: https://codepen.io/zfrisch/pen/ENpvOq

---

### Basic example of Elif:

```js
var scriptText = document.querySelector('#microTemplate').innerText,

parsed = scriptText.replace(/elif/g, "else if"),

fn = new Function(parsed);

fn();
```

```html
<script id="microTemplate" type="text/template">
  let a = 5;
  
  if(a < 5) console.log("a is less than 5");
  
  elif(a === 5) console.log("a is 5");
  
  else console.log("a is greater than 5");
</script>
```

**NOTE** Keep in mind these examples aren't filled with full-proof Regular Expressions. This is just a bare-bones example of *how you can* do simple transpiling. For instance if you put a string in the above code with `"elifant"` it will write `"else ifant"`.

---

### Conclusion

I don't know if I've stressed this enough, haha, but seriously **do *NOT* use this in Production**. :)

In any case I hope this trick helped answer your question! **Happy Coding!**

Answer (score -1):

You can't assign a statement to a variable, you can only assign an expression.

`if`,`else`, and `else if` are all statements (along with `try/catch`, `switch`, `for`, `while`, etc..)

So in short, there is no real way that bit can work.

To alias an existing function you simply assign the existing function to a new variable, like so:

```
const c = {}
c.l = console.log
c.l('console','.','log','arguments')
```